# How to show country, city name in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel

I'm using Cpanel, I would like to show country name and city name in login page, something like this: For example:

```
 Your IP address is :  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 Your Country name is: USA 
 Your City name is:  Seattle
```

For above information, I just can show IP address by following php code:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

How to show other user information such as country name and city name ?

Please guide me step by step how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to use a [GeoLocation API](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/Mapping%2BGeography/apis?category=19978%2C20233).

[ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) provides a simple plain text return interface but, like many geolocation APIs, it requires paid versions of the service if you exceed certain limitations (i.e. in the case of ipinfo.io, you require more than 1000 requests/day or SSL).

Using the non-JSON version of ipinfo.io as an example, your PHP code might look like:

```
<?php 

    // This turns on error display without messing with php.ini
    // Delete the following two lines in production

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // We avoid using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] directly with a custom variable
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    // Otherwise, using the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] directly
    //$city = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. '/city');
 
    // Using our custom $ip variable

    $city = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'. $ip. '/city');
    $country = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'. $ip. '/country');

    //$region = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'. $ip. '/region');
    

    // An alternate formatting of City State, Country
    //echo $city.' '.$region.', ' .$country;

    // Print our variables. <br> is a standard HTML line break.
    echo 'Your IP address is:   '.$ip;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Your Country name is: '.$country;
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo 'Your City name is:    '.$city;
?>
```

You can omit all lines with //, since these are just comments/examples. Likewise, the error display lines (ini_set/error_reporting) are for debugging only. The periods before and after the variables are necessary for concatenation. The URLs concatenate to

```
 Ex. http://ipinfo.io/123.123.123.123/city
```

and return plain text in this form. Check out the [ipinfo.io developers page](https://ipinfo.io/developers) for a few more ideas about what can be returned. The above code returns:

```
Ex.
    Your IP address is :  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Your Country name is: US
    Your City name is:  Las Vegas
```

Alternately, if you want "United States" vs. "US", you can try also try something like the [Geobytes City Details](https://geobytes.com/get-city-details-api/) legacy API. To return "United States":

```
<?php

    function getIP() {
      foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key) {
         if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
           foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
             if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                   return $ip;
                }
             } 
          }
       }
    }

    $tags=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://getcitydetails.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?fqcn='. getIP()), true);

    // Prints all available members of the $tags array, in case we forget our options
    //print_r($tags);

    // $tags[geobytesipaddress]) creates a non-fatal error so we use '' quotes around the array elements.
    print_r('Your IP address is: ' .$tags['geobytesipaddress']);
    echo '<br>';
    print_r('Your Country name is: ' .$tags['geobytescountry']);
    echo '<br>'; 
    print_r('Your City name is:    ' .$tags['geobytescity']);

?>
```

This is just slightly modified example code from the Geobytes page. As written, it duplicates the output of the first code example but with the full country name:

```
Ex.
    Your IP address is :  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Your Country name is: United States
    Your City name is:  Las Vegas
```

As a side note, the Geobytes API seems to support a few more options than ipinfo.io and allows a *much* higher non-paid request rate (if that matters).

Comment: Oh, Thanks for your perfect information, thumbs up